# Gradle sync Error : Cannot add a NexusRepository with name 'sonatype' as a NexusRepository with that name already exists

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to migrate my closed source library to MavenCentral & i as mentioned in the title, i got this issue when to trying to sync my project.

i followed the following gist : https://gist.github.com/zsmb13/56ed98c8fe916de441f2a9d8e060cd4a

full tutorial that i readed many times can be found here : https://proandroiddev.com/publishing-android-libraries-to-mavencentral-in-2021-8ac9975c3e52

And of course i used the new repos since i am a new sonatype user

```
nexusPublishing {
    repositories {
        sonatype {
            stagingProfileId = sonatypeStagingProfileId
            username = ossrhUsername
            password = ossrhPassword
            nexusUrl.set(uri("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/"))
            snapshotRepositoryUrl.set(uri("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"))
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand why am i getting this error, i am using gradle 5.2

Full Error :

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot add a
> NexusRepository with name 'sonatype' as a NexusRepository with that
> name already exists.

In case that gradle has an inner 'sonatype' named repository, how can i set the new URls for the new Users ?

Please help,
And Thank you for this amazing community